# jQuery inArray() always returning -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I would like to sort a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>L</li>
    <li>S</li>
    <li>XXS</li>
    <li>XS</li>
    <li>XL</li>
    <li>L</li>
</ul>
```

with Javascript and jQuery to get the correct order of Clothing Sizes
my attempt was this:

```
var mylist = jQuery('#filter-size .mana-list');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {

    var sizes = new Array();
    sizes = ["XXXS", "XXS", "XS", "S", "S-M", "S-L", "M", "M-L", "L", "L-XL", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"];

    var compA = jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase();

    var asize = jQuery.inArray(compA, sizes);
    var bsize = jQuery.inArray(compB, sizes);

    return (asize > bsize) ? -1 : (asize < bsize) ? 1 : 0;
})
```

my problem is that the inArray() function always returns -1
what am i doing wrong?

(note: I am usign jQuery in "No Conflict" mode)

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(compA)` and `console.log(asize)`

Comment: `inArray` is not always returning `-1` for me .. what version of jQuery? http://jsfiddle.net/jNnTG/

Comment: it ain't -1...see here: http://jsfiddle.net/qjxpX/

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Wxuw4/ -- you are not changing the order in the DOM, maybe that is your problem.

Comment: FYI, you have size "L" in there twice - was one of those meant to be "M"?

Comment: Hi I solved it. My mistake there were anchors-tags inside the list-items, so .text() returned the wrong result. Instead i used jQuery(a).children("a").text().toUpperCase();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code appears unnecessarily complicated.

This will also produce a sorted list of the items, and avoids expensive DOM (and jQuery) calls being used within the comparator function:

```
// get all of the text items, in order, in upper case
var listitems = jQuery('ul').children('li').map(function() {
    return jQuery(this).text().toUpperCase();
}).get();

// keep this outside the function to avoid instantiating it
// every time the comparator is called
var sizes = ["XXXS", "XXS", "XS", "S", "S-M", "S-L", "M",
                 "M-L", "L", "L-XL", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"];

// just compare the "inArray" values to sort    
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return jQuery.inArray(b, sizes) - jQuery.inArray(a, sizes);
})
```

Note the use of a simple minus operator in the comparator function - this one sorts from largest to smallest, and the comparator need only produce "negative, zero, positive", not "-1, 0, 1".

NB: this does not change the elements in the page - please clarify if that was your intent.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/v3hqB/

Comment: thanks! i used this code to change the list items in the page     jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });

Answer (score 0):

A followup to Alnitak excellent answer.

Your sort was fine. If you do want to update your display, something like the following (quickly written) will do the trick:

```
var newList = $('<ul></ul>');
newList.append(listitems);
mylist.replaceWith(newList);
```

(There may be a better way.... perhaps `newList` could be constructed with `listitems` in one shot.)

Comment: thanks! I used: jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });